# iOS : Can we access app's documents folder if device is jailbroken

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have stored some confidential data in a file in documents folder.I want to know if a iOS device is jailbroken then can someone access documents folder of app.If yes what can be the possibilities to avoid this because i don't want to reveal that data?

I have already one option with me to encrypt those files but this file is continuously being written and read.So continuous encrypt decrypt will use device resources(like battery,cpu) to great extent and my app is already suffering from battery issues.

Comment: How big is the file?  Can you hold its contents in memory?  If so, then i would decrypt the file into memory when the app launches and write it back and encrypt only when the app will resign active.

Comment: @Paulw11 file is not big(few kb).if user kills the app then i will  lose the data because it getting updated continuously.

Comment: That's why you should write the file in `willResignActive`; this method is called when the user taps the home button

Comment: but my app runs in background as well so i just cant rely on this because willResignActive does not get called if your app is in background and and you press home button twice.

Comment: True, but you can't be running continuously in the background unless you are getting continuous GPS location updates, in which case the GPS will be the major battery drain. Essentially there is no way that you can secure data held on the device against a sufficiently determined attacker who can jailbreak the device (it can be secured against someone who does not have the passcode and therefore can't jaikbreak the device)

Comment: You say that the data is "confidential"; are you worried that it may be accessed by the device owner or someone else. If the latter then iOS file protection should be enough as long as the device owner has set a passcode. If the former then all you can do is make it harder

Comment: @Paulw11 yes my app is getting continuous GPS locations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116359/discussion-between-paulw11-and-desert-rose).

Answer (score 1):

When your device is jailbroken it could be possible to access through for example :

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ED49734D-0E61-4BB4-B3CC-..../Documents/
```

You can set the `NSFileProtection` attribute on a file to have it encrypted using a key derived from the user's passcode. But `NSFileProtection` does not offer any real protection from code executed on the device with root privileges.

You can encrypt the data and store encryption keys localy (where you know). User could find the keys and decrypt everything. It's impossible to
guarantee the absolute security but it's a way to start.